# AngularJS Access JSON object as well as FileObject from http-get method's response

Tags: python, angularjs, json, tornado, http-get

I've created an application in AngularJS in which on an API request I want to get FileObject along with JSON Object.

I know how to download a FileObject if a http request contains a FileObject in response.

Code I use to download FileObject:

```
this.getFileObject = function() {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: DATA_URLS.MY_URL,
            responseType: 'arraybuffer'
        }).
        success(function(data, status, config) {
            // any required additional processing here
            deferred.resolve(data, status, config);
        }).
        error(function(data, status, config) {
            deferred.reject(data, status, config);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    };
```

Using above I can download files from backend response.

Tornado Handler looks some what like this for File download request.

```
class UploadFile(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, params):
        with open(file_location, 'rb') as source_file:
            self.write(source_file.read())
        self.finish()
```

I want to send a JSON Object along with file Object.

Code I am using to achieve this

```
class UploadFile(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, params):
        self.write({"JSON": df.to_json(orient="records", date_format='iso')})
        with open(file_location, 'rb') as source_file:
             self.write(source_file.read())
        self.on_finish()
```

I want to know how to access JSON Object as well as FileObject in same response. Correct me if something is wrong with tornado api Handler or AngularJS code.

Comment: You need to return a multipart response, i dont know tornado, but you should try returning a multipart response from server